# Reinitialize Slick js after successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slick.js

I am using Slick for a carousel implementation and everything works fine when the pages loads.What I am trying to achieve is that when i make an Ajax call to retrieve new data I still want the slick carousel implementation, at the moment i lose it.

I have put the call for slick into a function

```
function slickCarousel() {
  $('.skills_section').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
}
```

and then I call the function within my success callback

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/public/index',
    dataType: 'script',
    data: data_send,
      success: function() {
        slickCarousel();
      }
   });
```

But the function isn't being called. How can I reinitialize this js?

Comment: does the program reach the success function handler?

Comment: yes it does, so could i be missing something?

Comment: Since the carousel is already initialized, you would need to remove that event handler before re-initializing it. Just a guess

Comment: sorry if this is a dumb question but could you provide an example please

Answer (score 28):

You should use the unslick method:

```
function getSliderSettings(){
  return {
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: '/public/index',
  dataType: 'script',
  data: data_send,
  success: function() {
    $('.skills_section').slick('unslick'); /* ONLY remove the classes and handlers added on initialize */
    $('.my-slide').remove(); /* Remove current slides elements, in case that you want to show new slides. */
    $('.skills_section').slick(getSliderSettings()); /* Initialize the slick again */
  }
});
```

Comment: for me I had to use `$('.slick-media').slick('unslick').slick('reinit');`

Comment: This worked for me, @JosephMarikle is there docs on this method I didn't see it listed?

Comment: It saved my day. Thanks

Comment: In my case, I was simply resizing the window and in so doing, I transitioned from 2 slides to 1. Simply calling the .slick() function didn't work. However, I ran .slick('unslick'); then re-ran the the slick() function. Working perfectly

Answer (score 20):

The best way is you should destroy the slick slider after reinitializing it.

```js
function slickCarousel() {
  $('.skills_section').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
}
function destroyCarousel() {
  if ($('.skills_section').hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
    $('.skills_section').slick('destroy');
  }      
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: '/public/index',
  dataType: 'script',
  data: data_send,
  success: function() {
    destroyCarousel()
    slickCarousel();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 17):

```
$('#slick-slider').slick('refresh'); //Working for slick 1.8.1
```

Answer (score 15):

This should work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/public/index',
    dataType: 'script',
    data: data_send,
    success: function() {
        $('.skills_section').slick('reinit');
      }
});
```

Comment: 'reInit' is a slick event (that can be listened to to see when slick reinitializes), not a method that can be called to reinitialize the carousel.

Comment: mcrider, are you sure it's not both?

Comment: According to their docs, it is only an event.  But I did just try this method on one of my carousels and it did indeed seem to work.

Comment: I tried it and it crashed my page, I found that destroying it and reinitialising it was a more successful way. Maybe there have been some updates to the script since 2016?

Comment: @mcrider The plugin has a [prototype function](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js#L1925) `reinit` which is called because `.slick('reinit')` simply executes the function with name of the passed string. Since the plugin's docs don't mention this I wouldn't use it though, because there might be unwanted side effects (as experienced with crashing the browser). Using `.slick('unslick')` and then `.slick(config)` is probably more reliant.

Answer (score 4):

### Note: I am not sure if this is correct but you can give it a try and see if this works.

There is a `unslick` method which de-initializes the carousel, so you might try using that before re-initializing it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/public/index',
    dataType: 'script',
    data: data_send,
    success: function() {
        $('.skills_section').unslick();  // destroy the previous instance
        slickCarousel();
      }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, makes a lot more sense on what you where pointing out in the comments, unfortunately i get an error `TypeError: _.$slides is null if (_.$slides.parent().hasClass('slick-track')) {` so im assuming it hasn't unslicked so to speak, but ill keep looking into it, thanks again

Comment: Update: syntax is now:  $(slider).slick('unslick');

Answer (score 4):

I was facing an issue where the Slick carousel wasn't refreshing on new data instead it was appending new slides to the previous ones, I found a solution that solved my problem, it's very simple.

> **TL;DR**
> Try passing ***unslick***, then assign your new data which is being rendered inside slick carousel, and then initialize slick
> again. these were the steps for me:
>
> ```
> jQuery('.class-or-#id').slick('unslick');
> myData = my-new-data;
> jQuery('.class-or-#id').slick({slick-options});
> ```

**Notes:**
***Check the slick.js website for syntax just in case***. Also, make sure you are not using unslick before slick is even initialized. What that means is, simply initialize like this the very first ajax call
`jquery('.my-class').slick({slick-options})`
And once it's initialized then follow the above steps. You might wanna use if-else.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, it helped me!

```
$('.slider-selector').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  setPosition: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to unslick the carousel before the ajax call starts, but you can't do that until there is already a slick carousel. So, I set a variable to 0 and only run unslick after it changed

```
var slide = 0
if(slide>0)      
$('#ui-id-1').slick('unslick');

        $.ajax({
            //do stuff, here
        },
        success: function( data ) {

            $('#ui-id-1').slick();
            slide++;

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to use the `unslick` setting or function(depending on your version of slick) as stated in the other answers but that did not work for me. I'm getting some errors from slick that seem to be related to [this](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/369).

What did work for now, however, is removing the `slick-initialized` and `slick-slider` classes from the container before reinitializing slick, like so:

```
function slickCarousel() {
    $('.skills_section').removeClass("slick-initialized slick-slider");
    $('.skills_section').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
}
```

Removing the classes doesn't seem to initiate the destroy event(not tested but makes sense) but does cause the later `slick()` call to behave properly so as long as you don't have any triggers on destroy, you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

Here we go, guys!
It helped me

```
$('.slick-slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
   infinite: false,
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   dots: true,
   arrows: false,
   touchThreshold: 9
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slick Version: 1.8.0

```
 function getSliderSettings() {
                return {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    loop: true,
                    arrows: true,
                    dots: false,
                }
            }
    
    
    $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/public/index',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: some_data,
            success: function(response) {
                    $('[data-role="slick-slider"]').slick('unslick');
                    $('[data-role="slick-slider"]').html($(response).html());
                    $('[data-role="slick-slider"]').slick(getSliderSettings());
              }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, above answers are correct, there is one more problem regarding showing new slides with updated/new data after array has been updated and then need to refresh the slick slider instance.

If we don't do like this, then somehow slick keeps showing older data which was bounded there before updating the array even if the array is already updated.

So the code with newer frameworks available and ES6 approach might look something like this.

Let's say we are showing array of data via loop in modern library like vue, react, angular or alpine js and we have array of `shops` to show as a slider.

Each time someone triggers some action, array(and eventually dom) is updated but we have to manually tell slick slider to update the slides data as per the data in the new array. here we have data in the form of `shops` array.

```
  {
        shops: [],
        init() {
            let self = this;
            // watch for your data and provide callback function after it has been updated
            // this $watch is example from alpine js but similar could be available in other framrworks
            self.$watch('shops',(currentShops,oldShops) => {
                //currentshops holds the new value of shops after update
                //oldShops holds older value before update

                //first remove all slides that were attached with slick before shops array was updated (sorted for example)
                $('#shops-section-slider.slick-initialized').slick('slickRemove', null, null, true);
                //After this, add new slides after shops has been updated(sorted)
                // via template that accepts shop as an argument
                currentShops.forEach(function(shop,index) {
                    $('#shops-section-slider.slick-initialized').slick('slickAdd', self.getSliderTmpl(shop));
                })
                //after adding and removing is completed, 
                //finally just call refresh to prevent reinit entirely.
                $('#shops-section-slider.slick-initialized').slick('refresh');
            })
            //shopsPromise only does slider creation and other things when data has been updated in dom.
            shopsPromise.then(function(data) {
                //update shops here via data that has been recieved
                shops.push(data)
            }).then(function() {
                //crate slider after promise is resolved
                $('#shops-section-slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
                    //your slick settings
                })
            });
        },
        
        getSliderTmpl(shop) {
            return `<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 d-flex flex-column shops-section">
                <div class="row flex-grow-1 flex-column flex-xxl-row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-xxl-6">
                        <div class="shops-img position-relative">
                            <strong class="shops-title-card d-block d-xxl-none">${shop.whateveravailable}</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>`;
        }
    }
```

and inside the html, we even don't need the `<template>` element which is used as looping in alpine js as it creates incorrect width and issues due to one more slides there so we can omit that, and thus managing entire slider data and template both from js only.

```
<div class="row shops-section-wrapper" id="shops-section-slider"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

After calling an request, set timeout to initialize slick slider.

```
var options = {
    arrows: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    centerPadding: '10px'
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: review_url+"?page="+page,
    success: function(result){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".reviews-page-carousel").slick(options)
        }, 500);
    }
})
```

Do not initialize slick slider at start. Just initialize after an AJAX with timeout. That should work for you.